# This for /r loop works in an unintended way

Tags: batch-file

I making a batch file to prefix a group of folders with @, it doesn't touch the folders but it replaces the first letter of everything else with @:

```
for /r %%a in (C:\example\*) do ren %%a @*
```

I want it to do:

```
C:\Example
   @folder 0
    subfolder 0
   @folder 1 
    subfolder 1
     text0.txt
  text1.txt
```

but it does

```
C:\Example
     folder 0
      subfolder 0
     folder 1 
      subfolder 1
        @ext0.txt
 @ext1.txt
```

What can I do to fix it?

Edit1: 
thanks to @Squshman I figured out that /r is the wrong command I wanted /d but that raised another problem.

the new code is

```
for /d %%a in (c:\example\*) do ren %%a @*
```

that in turn made a syntax error that I can't figure out. it spits out

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

the syntax is correct from what I see from ren /?

Comment: The `/R` option by itself recursively enumerates FILES.  The `/D` option will enumerate folders.  You can use them together but use the path after the `/R` like the help file shows.  `FOR /D /R C:\example %%G IN (*) do ren %%G @%%G`

Comment: `for` enumerates *files*, unless you add `/D` to enumerate directories. `ren` does not seem to accept wildcards when source is a directory, but you do not need such as you have `%%a` anyway...